# ¿Como puedo ordenar un arreglo dinámico alfabéticamente?

Tags: c++

Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer esto. Para poner en contexto, tengo una estructura representando una tienda de discos la cual tiene las siguientes características para las canciones que tiene:

```
struct Discotienda{
    string titulo;
    string interprete;
    string autor;
    double duracion;
};
```

En base esa esta cree un arreglo dinámico con 3 canciones diferentes cada una con sus respectivas características:

```
Discotienda *p;
    p=new Discotienda[3];
    p[3]={"DeMusicaLigera","SodaStereo","GustavoCerati",3.22,
                   "CartasSinMarcar","AndresCalamaro","AndresCalamaro",4.12,
                   "MuevanLasIndustrias","LosPrisioneros","JorgeGonzales",3.49};
```

Ahora debo crear una opción que permita buscar una canción por titulo o interprete y esta se hace de acuerdo a un indice que básicamente es otro arreglo, basado en el arreglo p y que este ordenado alfabéticamente según la canción o el interprete, la cosa es que no se como ordenar este indice alfabeticamente como me piden que lo haga.

Por ahora en la función de buscar titulo he hecho esto:

```
void BuscarPorTitulo(int *p)
{
    string *indice;
    indice=new string[3];
    indice=p;

}
```

¿Como podría hacer esto entonces? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Corrección crítica: es Soda Stereo* ;)

Comment: En el título indicas que quieres ordenar algo alfabéticamente, en el cuerpo indicas que quieres buscar algo por índice. No me aclaro ¿cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Digo que quiero ordenar alfabeticamente el indice, perdon si no fui claro

Comment: Que el tipo de arreglo sea un arreglo dinámico asignado con `new` ¿es una restricción de diseño? Si no lo es, me gustaría proponerte una solución usando las herramientas provistas por C++, que son std::vector y std::sort.

Comment: si lo es, debo hacerlo de esta forma, no me han mostrado vector ni sort

Comment: Y si te pido que ordenes un arreglo de numeros? Puedes hacer eso? Si lo puedes hacer, solo tienes que aplicar el mismo principio a tu arrelgo. Lo unico que cambiaria es como comparas cual es menor que otro. Para eso te recomiendo que veas como sobrecargar el operador `<`.

Comment: osea se puede hacer un ordenamiento de burbuja por ejemplo pero con caracteres o strings?

Comment: @Rinxs. Si no haces un `@nombre` no me llega la notificacion. Si, puedes hacer un ordenamiento de burbuja. Si sobrecargas el operador `<` bastara con que cambies los tipos de los parametros de la funcion que ya tengas que lo haga. Pero de todas formas sigue el mismo principio.

Comment: @Pablochaches De acuerdo, muchas gracias, yo creia que no se podia hacer eso.

Answer (score 8):

> En base esa esta cree un arreglo dinámico con 3 canciones diferentes cada una con sus respectivas características:

```
Discotienda *p;
    p=new Discotienda[3];
    p[3]={"DeMusicaLigera","SodaStereo","GustavoCerati",3.22,
                   "CartasSinMarcar","AndresCalamaro","AndresCalamaro",4.12,
                   "MuevanLasIndustrias","LosPrisioneros","JorgeGonzales",3.49};
```

Realmente el código debería estar así:

```
Discotienda *p = new Discotienda[3] {
    // Cada elemento de la lista tiene sus propias llaves
    { "DeMusicaLigera", "SodaStereo", "GustavoCerati", 3.22 },  
    { "CartasSinMarcar", "AndresCalamaro", "AndresCalamaro", 4.12 },
    { "MuevanLasIndustrias", "LosPrisioneros", "JorgeGonzales", 3.49 }
};
```

> la cosa es que no se como ordenar este indice alfabeticamente como me piden que lo haga.

Para ordenar puedes empezar por usar el algoritmo de la burbuja o *bubble sort*. Hay otros más eficientes pero también son más complejos de entender y de implementar:

```
void ordenar(Discotienda * lista, int numElementos) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < numElementos-1; i++)     
    {  
        for (int j = 0; j < numElementos-i-1; j++)
        {
            if (lista[j].titulo > lista[j+1].titulo) 
            {
                Discotienda temp = lista[j];
                lista[j] = lista[j+1];
                lista[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

¿Cómo se usa? Facil

```
ordenar(p, 3);
```

Después de eso ya deberías tener tu lista ordenada por el título.

Answer (score 4):

Ordenar elementos no es dependiente del tipo de colección de objetos; así pues, no tiene importancia si es un arreglo u otro tipo de colección y no es relevante si es de tamaño dinámico o tamaño estático.

Lo que es relevante para ordenar elementos es que los elementos sean ordenables, y para que los elementos sean ordenables deben ser comparados entre si para averiguar si un elemento es menor que otro. Por lo tanto, debemos crear un operador de comparación:

```
struct Discotienda{
    string titulo;
    string interprete;
    string autor;
    double duracion;
};

bool operator<(const Discotienda &a, const Discotienda &b)
{
    return a.titulo < b.titulo;
}
```

Con esto, podemos pasar la colección de `Discotienda` a la función [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) de [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm):

```
std::sort(p, p + 3);
```

Pero esto sólo nos ordena por un campo (`Discotienda::titulo`) y no podemos hacer que el `operator <` ordene por diferentes campos a conveniencia. Por lo tanto la mejor opción será pasar a `std::sort` una lambda de ordenación:

```
std::sort(p, p + 3, [](const Discotienda &a, const Discotienda &b)
{
    return a.titulo < b.titulo;
}); // Ordena por titulo

std::sort(p, p + 3, [](const Discotienda &a, const Discotienda &b)
{
    return a.interprete < b.interprete;
}); // Ordena por interprete
```

Pero estas opciones nos ordenan la colección original, sin embargo tú quieres ordenar los índices dejando la colección original intacta, en ese caso además de los datos necesitamos los índices:

```
Discotienda p[] {
    "DeMusicaLigera","SodaStereo","GustavoCerati",3.22,
    "CartasSinMarcar","AndresCalamaro","AndresCalamaro",4.12,
    "MuevanLasIndustrias","LosPrisioneros","JorgeGonzales",3.49
};

int indices[] { 0, 1, 2 };

std::cout << "Datos antes de ordenar:\n";
for (const auto &d : p)
    std::cout << '\t' << d << '\n';
std::cout << "Indices antes de ordenar:\n\t";
for (const int &indice : indices)
    std::cout << indice << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';

// Ordena los indices, no los datos
std::sort(indices, indices + 3, [p](int a, int b) {
    return p[a].titulo < p[b].titulo;
});

std::cout << "Datos despues de ordenar:\n";
for (const auto &d : p)
    std::cout << '\t' << d << '\n';
std::cout << "Indices despues de ordenar:\n\t";
for (const int &indice : indices)
    std::cout << indice << ' ';
```

El código anterior [genera la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##vVJNixpBED3P/IpiAn6QiWTdvURlYVFYDAoL5qYeyu6OaRi7hv7YQ4K/3VTPjO6OMbeQW1f1636v3itRlp9EgWZ/On3QRhRBKphoct4qPDymbz0s9mS1/9FqMkyb/WOa8iEIDzPtBHmtjET4lSbOy9GoxoDXPhQ0bje18cqWVnl1dYHBk@WepLArFMhgUWgy4/Q4jmQMbCRCh0plkdGTSe/qIgdBxrVVdWQ/ZWVMGawBgskEsm@VtBFksZKDWmk8d6GbJkmEzC9CL7A37W3oU5R@QVWDtAGzZpgL5t10acrfwgG16VU630sv19toapLN1DI4LXCh9zx6lmcrkrhiNYq4eA7O4ytNoys6y@8Hw2EeX03RenQrbZZoBVpGPhlplZtigQe0dKPxMLir3y6DekWzQDc3MsSI0DF8Qe7FasfKlaXY@Ep2r57J/MRCuUj98CVNYmJJnEobqYVycQr4nMNdDkOoLqvYBAVfpTHjMB0gu@uAd4ysVAbtaGMy3ofvbGavTjU6y3HCCMo@a2x90t34buVtXZju@JplXou5xbPxV0xRfKdWz2zNGH9wNoA66mu@WsN5x8n6XvNNfv4PPsJ9Duty24t0mFesu36VeLOt5Rq3l@3kaneumO3Y/5uTUrky/BcvbzL9GzePp9Nv):

```
Datos antes de ordenar:
    Titulo: DeMusicaLigera Interprete: SodaStereo Autor: GustavoCerati Duracion: 3.22
    Titulo: CartasSinMarcar Interprete: AndresCalamaro Autor: AndresCalamaro Duracion: 4.12
    Titulo: MuevanLasIndustrias Interprete: LosPrisioneros Autor: JorgeGonzales Duracion: 3.49
Indices antes de ordenar:
    0 1 2 
Datos despues de ordenar:
    Titulo: DeMusicaLigera Interprete: SodaStereo Autor: GustavoCerati Duracion: 3.22
    Titulo: CartasSinMarcar Interprete: AndresCalamaro Autor: AndresCalamaro Duracion: 4.12
    Titulo: MuevanLasIndustrias Interprete: LosPrisioneros Autor: JorgeGonzales Duracion: 3.49
Indices despues de ordenar:
    1 0 2
```

Comment: En C++20 se puede [generar la comparación automáticamente](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons).